# Drop Down menu is not showing properly in HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.templatemo_menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.templatemo_menu:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#templatemo_menu {
    float: left;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

```html
<div id="templatemo_menu">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>

                        <li ><a href="Aboutus.html" class="dropbtn" >Coindia</a>
                        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
                        <li><a href="http://www.flashmo.com" target="_parent">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.koflash.com" target="_parent">Facility</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>

                    </ul>       

   </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->
```

I want to create submenu in HTML. Here i have created menu and submenu but it is not appearing properly. Please help me with this.i want the sub-menu open to down side when cursor is placed on it Here is the css and html relating to it

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#templatemo_menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

#templatemo_menu:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#templatemo_menu {
    float: left;
   // height: 37px;
    margin-top: 12px;
   // overflow:hidden;

}
```

```html
<div id="templatemo_menu">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>

                        <li ><a href="Aboutus.html" class="dropbtn" >Coindia</a>
                        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
                        <li><a href="http://www.flashmo.com" target="_parent">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.koflash.com" target="_parent">Facility</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>

                    </ul>       

   </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->
```

`<div id="templatemo_menu">` You have given id `templatemo_menu` and in you css you have given `.templatemo_menu`.You have to use `#templatemo_menu` for `id`. Also change the style of `#templatemo_menu`

```
#templatemo_menu {
    float: left;
   // height: 37px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    //overflow:hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few small edits will cause the drop down to work, there appears to be some other work left to do.

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.templatemo_menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.templatemo_menu .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
.templatemo_menu:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#templatemo_menu {
    float: left;
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

```html
    <div>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>

                        <li class="templatemo_menu"><a href="Aboutus.html" class="dropbtn" >Coindia</a>
                        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
                        <li><a href="http://www.flashmo.com" target="_parent">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.koflash.com" target="_parent">Facility</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>

                    </ul>       

                </div> <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->
```